# How to animate from right while adding a xib file to ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, animation

Here I am adding a view from `xib` when tapping on the menu button which is in my navigation bar right button, my problem is this view is coming from left to right but I want it to come from right to left.

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: { () -> Void in    
navController.navigationBar.frame = CGRectMake(-nibView.frame.width, 20, 
navController.navigationBar.frame.width, 
navController.navigationBar.frame.height)         
nibView.frame = CGRectMake( viewSize.frame.width - nibView.frame.width , 0, 
viewSize.frame.width, viewSize.frame.height)                      
viewSize.addSubview(nibView)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

er.. First.

Create a new class named Animator and inherit NSObject and UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning.

Then add properties to the class:

```
let animationDuration = 2.0
var operation: UINavigationControllerOperation = .Push
```

Then implement two functions:

```
func transitionDuration(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> NSTimeInterval {
     return animationDuration 
}

func animateTransition(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
}
```

Then in your mainViewController, extension UINavigationCOntrollerDelegate, in viewDidLoad() implement delegate = self and declare:

```
let transition = Animator()
```

In the extension, add this function:

```
func navigationController(navigationController: UINavigationController, animationControllerForOperation operation: UINavigationControllerOperation, fromViewController fromVC: UIViewController, toViewController toVC: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
   transition.operation = operation
   return transition 
}
```

In Animator, implement your UIViewControllerContextTransitioning.

```
weak var storedContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?
```

then in function animateTranstion:

```
storedContext = transitionContext

let fromVC = transitionContext.viewControllerForKey( UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey) as! MasterViewController

let toVC = transitionContext.viewControllerForKey( UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey) as! DetailViewController

transitionContext.containerView()?.addSubview(toVC.view)
```

At last, create your own animator. :)